# How to use popup on amp page?

Tags: popup, amp-html

I am using amp on my site, users are all mobile and amp. I got the popup ad. But when I add a popup to the amp page, the amp page breaks down and it gets out of circulation.

how do I solve this problem?

code in the example I used.

Thanks

```
<script>
  var username= "***";
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//POPADRESS.JS"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the
[ask] link for more details on how to ask a question and update your question accordingly.

Comment: anyone can help me

Comment: @mranderson use amp-lightbox, https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-lightbox/

Comment: thanks, how can i use it. Can you show an example?

Comment: @mranderson I have given the example link, how to implement. Still you need example let me know.

Comment: @BachchaSingh my code knowledge is not very strong. How can I combine with the popup code I have given above thanks

Comment: still need help any master can help me

Comment: @BachchaSingh Your link does not seem to be working anymore.

Comment: @SawThinkarNayHtoo https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-lightbox/?format=websites

Answer (score -1):

You can't execute your own authored JavaScript on AMP pages, what you're trying to do will not work. You'll need to refactor your advertisement to use one of the approved AMP components found on the AMP [components page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components).

Please refer to the ['How AMP Works' documentation](https://www.ampproject.org/learn/about-how/).

> JavaScript is powerful, it can modify just about every aspect of the
>   page, but it can also block DOM construction and delay page rendering
>   (see also Adding interactivity with JavaScript). To keep JavaScript
>   from delaying page rendering, AMP allows only asynchronous JavaScript.
>
> AMP pages can’t include any author-written JavaScript. Instead of
>   using JavaScript, interactive page features are handled in custom AMP
>   elements. The custom AMP elements may have JavaScript under the hood,
>   but they’re carefully designed to make sure they don’t cause
>   performance degradation.
>
> While third-party JS is allowed in iframes, it cannot block rendering.
>   For example, if third-party JS uses the super-bad-for-performance
>   document.write API, it does not block rendering the main page.